# OTF reprojection and reprojecting layer not working in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

more troubles in QGIS.
I georeferenced this raster in Corrego Alegre UTM23S and loaded up, so project CRS automatically changed to that. So far so good. I need it to be however in WGS84 UTM 23S. None of the two possible ways will do. Enabling OTF reprojection and setting project CRS to WGS84UTM makes the raster layer disappear. Even after "zoom to layer". It's just not visible.
The other way would be to save the layer in a different CRS with right-click-save as. Doesn't work either. I just did as other times before, but the file is not saved. I open the folder where I sent it to, and it's not there.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

`Rightclick -> Saxe As ...` to reproject a layer only works for vector layers.

Raster layers are a bit more complicated, you have to use `Raster -> Projections -> Warp(Reproject)` with a new file name and source CRS different from target CRS.

Comment: Very interesting. Thanks @AndreJ.

How about the OTF reprojection not working... Do you have any ideia of why the layer is gone when I change the project CRS?

Comment: Raster > Projections > Warp didn't work either.

Getting this error message: "ERROR 1: Too many points (5625 out of 5625) failed to transform,
unable to compute output bounds."

So far really exhaustive to use QGIS.

Comment: Can you add the extent of the Corrego Alegre UTM layer, as reported by the Layer properties -> Metadata tab?

Comment: Sure:      Layer Spatial Reference System
+proj=utm +zone=23 +south +ellps=intl +towgs84=-206,172,-6,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
Layer Extent (layer original source projection)
549.5058157301625670,7642.8538327836458848 : 580.7578524659228378,7680.4526190025198957

Comment: The X coordinates look rather strange for UTM. What area or town should the data cover?

Comment: Thanks AndreJ, there is a typo in one of the GCPs for the x coordinate. Sorry for taking your time.